# Extending jQuery with typescript and webpack

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I'm converting a project using typescript using all global definitions and direct javascript compilation to using modules and assembling them into a bundle with webpack. In some cases I'll attach a method to jQuery to create the class.

So I might have some classes/interfaces like this:

```
interface IMyClassOptions {
    //....
}

class MyClass {
    constructor(target: JQuery, options?: IMyClassOptions){
        //....
    }
}

interface JQuery {
    myClass(options?: IMyClassOptions): JQuery;
}

$.fn.myClass = function(options?: IMyClassOptions) {
    const instance = new MyClass(this, options);
    this.data("myClass", instance);
    return this;
}
```

Which works fine when compiled directly to javascript with the script dropped in the page. But now if I `export interface IMyClassOptions` and `export class MyClass` and assemble with webpack, then just those items get exported and the code to attach to jQuery doesn't get included in the bundle.

I can think of a few workarounds:

- Create a js file that attaches the function, and import that
- Add a static bootstrap function to the class to perform it, and have modules using MyClass call the bootstrap function

But I'd really like something automated that doesn't require extra code to set things up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp I ended up figuring it out.

Solution is to perform the operation in a function call to assign a static property in the class definition like:

```
declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        myClass(): JQuery;
    }
}

export class MyClass {
    static readonly bootstrapped = (() => {
        if(!("myClass" in $.fn)){
            $.fn.myClass = function(options?: IMyClassOptions){
                this.data("myClass", new MyClass(options));
                return this;
            }
        }

        return true;
    })();
```

And then if only the extended jQuery method is used need to `import "./myclass"`